# Finding the probability of a minimised dice roll with a reroll.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

Fix $X$ as a value between $1$ and $10.$
Consider a game of rolling three six-sided dice, where the highest valued die rolled is removed. If the sum of the resulting two dice is equal to or less than $X$, do nothing. If the sum of the resulting two dice is greater than $X$, reroll all three dice and apply the afore noted removal process again.

How would you calculate the probability of obtaining a value less than or equal to a chosen $X$ in this game, with the minimisation and reroll?

Comment: Hint: You can assume for the purposes of calculation that you *always* re-roll, and you succeed if on either roll the sum of the values on the two smaller dice is less than or equal to $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you've excluded $X=11$ and $X=12$.

If the lower two dice have the same value $k$, and thus a sum of $2k$, there is $1$ result in which the highest die is also $k$ and $3(6-k)$ results in which the highest die is higher, for a total of $19-3k$.

If the lower two dice have different values $k\lt l$, and thus a sum of $k+l$, there are $3$ results in which the highest die is also $l$ and $6(6-l)$ results in which the highest die is higher, for a total of $39-6l$.

Thus, for odd $n\le 
7$, the number of ways to get a sum of $n$ from the lower two dice is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}(39-6(n-k))
&=&
\frac{(39-6n)(n-1)}2+6\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac{n-1}2\cdot\frac{n+1}2
\\
&=&
\frac{2(-6n^2+45n-39)+3(n^2-1)}4\;,
\\
&=&
\frac94(9-n)(n-1)
\end{eqnarray}

whereas for $n=9$ it's $39-6\cdot6+39-6\cdot5=12$ and for $n=11$ it's $39-6\cdot6=3$.

For even $n\le6$, the number of ways to get a sum of $n$ from the lower two dice is

\begin{eqnarray}
19-3\cdot\frac n2+\sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1}(39-6(n-k))
&=&
19-3\cdot\frac n2+(39-6n)\left(\frac n2-1\right)+6\cdot\frac12\cdot\left(\frac n2-1\right)\cdot\frac n2
\\
&=&
\frac{4\cdot19-6n+(39-6n)(2n-4)+3(n-2)n}4\;,
\\
&=&
\frac{-9n^2+90n-80}4\;,
\end{eqnarray}

whereas for even $n\ge8$ the number of ways to get a sum of $n$ from the lower two dice is

\begin{eqnarray}
19-3\cdot\frac n2+\sum_{k=n-6}^{n/2-1}(39-6(n-k))
&=&
\frac{-9n^2+90n-80}4-\sum_{k=1}^{n-7}(39-6(n-k))
\\
&=&
\frac{-9n^2+90n-80}4-(39-6n)(n-7)-6\cdot\frac12(n-7)(n-6)
\\
&=&
\frac{-9n^2+90n-80-4(39-6n)(n-7)-12(n-7)(n-6)}4
\\
&=&\frac{3n^2-78n+508}4
\end{eqnarray}

To summarize, we have the following numbers $a_n$ of ways of getting a sum of $n$ in the lower two dice:

\begin{array}{c|c}
n&a_n\\\hline
2&16\\
3&27\\
4&34\\
5&36\\
6&34\\
7&27\\
8&19\\
9&12\\
10&7\\
11&3\\
12&1
\end{array}

The sum is $6^3=216$, as it should be. Now add up the numbers $a_n$ for $n\le X$ and divide by $216$ to obtain the probabilities $p_X$ for obtaining a sum less than or equal to $X$ with the lower two dice:

\begin{array}{c|c}
X&p_X\\\hline
2&\frac{16}{216}\\
3&\frac{43}{216}\\
4&\frac{77}{216}\\
5&\frac{113}{216}\\
6&\frac{147}{216}\\
7&\frac{174}{216}\\
8&\frac{193}{216}\\
9&\frac{205}{216}\\
10&\frac{212}{216}\\
11&\frac{215}{216}\\
12&\frac{216}{216}
\end{array}

As noted by @kccu in a comment, you effectively have two tries to get $X$ or less, so the probability to succeed is $1-(1-p_X)^2=2p_X-p_X^2$.